# Splitting Dataframe based on corresponding numpy array values

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have pandas dataframe A that looks like :

```
    2007-12-31    50230.62
    2008-01-02    48646.84
    2008-01-03    48748.04
    2008-01-04    46992.22
    2008-01-07    46491.28
    2008-01-08    45347.72
    2008-01-09    45681.68
    2008-01-10    46430.5
```

Where the date column is the index. I also have an numpy array B of the same length which has element -1, 0 and 1. What is the cleanest way to split the dataframe A into 3 dataframes such that the rows with equal corresponding B elements are grouped together. For eg. if B = numpy.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0]) then the dataframe should be split into :

```
    X
    2007-12-31    50230.62
    2008-01-02    48646.84
    2008-01-03    48748.04
    2008-01-10    46430.5

    Y
    2008-01-04    46992.22
    2008-01-07    46491.28

    Z
    2008-01-08    45347.72
    2008-01-09    45681.68
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to utilize [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) from pandas, then you have the option to keep them grouped so you're not doubling your data. But you can always assign then

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import io

data = """    2007-12-31    50230.62
    2008-01-02    48646.84
    2008-01-03    48748.04
    2008-01-04    46992.22
    2008-01-07    46491.28
    2008-01-08    45347.72
    2008-01-09    45681.68
    2008-01-10    46430.5"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delimiter='\s+', header=None)
B = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0])

df['B'] = B

df_groups = df.groupby(['B'])

x = df_groups.get_group((0))
y = df_groups.get_group((-1))
z = df_groups.get_group((1))
```

The `0,-1,1` are the names based on the `B` value.